# Dynamic Dropdown menu using PHP & mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to build a dropdown menu but I'm not getting my desired results. Here's my code:

```
<?php require_once 'core/init.php'?>

<?php
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent = 0';
$pquery = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
?>

<?php while($parent = mysqli_fetch_assoc($pquery)):?>
<?php 
            $parent_id = $parent['id'];
            $sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent = "parent_id"';
            $cquery = mysqli_query($db,$sql2);
    ?>



            <li class='dropdown'>
                <a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>
                    <?php echo $parent['id'];?><span class='caret'</span</a>                    
                    <ul class='dropdown-menu' role='menu'>  

                        <?php while($child = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cquery)):>
                        <li><a href='#'><?php echo $child['parent'];?></a>
</li>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </ul>
            </li>
        <?php endwhile;?>
```

My DB is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9pTD.png) and the result is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iv2y1.png).

Comment: what do you want ? via ajax or not ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try with console phpmyadmin before write codes in page.

I think your codes is wrong.

Your code must like this

```
$parent_id = $parent['id'];
$sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent = '.$parent_id;
```

I suggest to you for use ajax to be beautiful again.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still fairly new to programming (less than a month). the code works btw. thank you very much :)